# Задержка времени в java

Tags: awt, java, многопоточность

Пытаюсь сделать задержку времени через Thread, вот таким макаром:

```
private Thread thread; 
 ...
private void initComponents() {
 thread = new Thread(); 
 thread.start();
 ...
public void Draw(Graphics g) throws Exception {
 while (true) {
  g.clearRect(sX, sY, fX, fY);
  g.drawLine(sX, sY, fX-2, fY-2);
  ...прорисовка компонентов...
  for (int i = sY + 50; i < fY; i += 50) {
   g.drawLine(sX, i, fX, i);
  }
  for (int j = sX + 50; j < fX; j += 50) {
   g.drawLine(j, sY, j, fY);
  }
  thread.sleep(90);                    // видимо, здесь ошибка
}
```

Проблема в том, что после запуска вроде всё идёт прекрасно, но окно не закрывается, хотя `setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE)` прописано перед инициализацией. Подскажите, что исправить.

Comment: а задержка причем тут?

Comment: видете другое объяснение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну поскольку у вас бесконечный цикл, то управление никогда не передается на гуйный тред (GUI Thread), соответственно оконная система не получает сигналов управления.

Пересмотрите логику своей проги - [фтыкать сюда](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Comment: Это не единственная проблема. Созданный thread честно спит свои 90 мс, но во времени он никак не связан с основным или гуевым тредом.

Comment: Barmaley, братан!

Comment: @bald2b Да, брат2 - что случилось?